# PHP better solution than for each loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have this timetable where a first loop a bunch of members from the database with and while-loop. Inside the `while`-loop I have an `foreach`-loop. How ever, the `foreach`-loops makes the whole timetable very slow, and I need an different approach to this problem.
What it looks like now.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblstaff ORDER BY strName ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
$user_id = $row['intId'];

$arr = array($one, $two, $three, $four, $five, $six, $seven);

foreach ($arr as $w) {
$week = $w;                         

$sql_offtime = mysql_query("SELECT tbloffwork.intId, tbloffwork.intWhoId, tbloffwork.strWeek
FROM tblstaff, tbloffwork
WHERE tbloffwork.intWhoId = '$user_id' AND tbloffwork.strWeek = '$week'");
$rwOff = mysql_fetch_array($sql_offtime);

$sql_work = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT tblstaff.intId as staffId, tblstaff.strName, tblworktable.intId, tblworktable.intWhoId, tblworktable.strElapsed, tblworktable.strNotes
FROM tblstaff, tblworktable
WHERE tblworktable.intWhoId = '$user_id' AND tblworktable.strElapsed = '$week'");
$rw_work = mysql_fetch_array($sql_work);

if($rwOff['strWeek'] == $week) {

 $td_stat = "timetable-td-background-yellow";   

} elseif($rw_work['strElapsed'] != "") { 

 $td_stat = "timetable-td-background-green"; 

} else { 

     $td_week = "timetable-td-background-red"; 

}


if($rw_work['strNotes'] != ""){

 $notes = "<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o mediumsmall'></i>";

} else { $notes = $null; }

echo "<td align='right' valign='top' id='timetable-td-small-square' class='". $td_week ."''>". $notes ."</td>";

} 

}
```

Is there a better way to approach this instead of going with the `foreach` method?

Comment: What's making it slow is not simply using a foreach loop; its what you're doing in the loop, which you didn't post exactly.

Comment: ...especially access database for each user

Comment: Please show more of your code, including both loops. If you can possibly un-nest the loops, it might make a huge difference.

Comment: I updated now, changes some variable names and database-names, so if there are any errors like thats, its cause I change it

Comment: you execute 2*7*N (where N is number of users) queries instead of 2, so yes it has to be slow

Comment: if this is all your code, you never use $row and you never initialize $user_id. Maybe it should be $user_id = $row['id']

Comment: yes there is $user_id too, missed it when i pasted it.

Comment: lulco, yes, and Im not sure how i should go about to sort it out? cause like this, well, its not working to put it mildly.

Comment: wooops. i think i saw my mistake now. lol. Thanks for pointing that out lulco. Those sql executions where messy.

Comment: just create list of user ids and weeks first and then run those 2 queries with condition like this: WHERE tbloffwork.intWhoId IN (implode(',', $userIds)) AND tblworktable.strElapsed IN (implode(',', $weeks))

Comment: Thanks, I did about that, just that the execution looks a bit different, but the idea is the same. I didnt notice at first that I messed up the first execution like that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

foreach makes a copy of the set, you can use while instead

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks, i tried, but its the same outcome, very slow. Maybe its due to the checking of the database inside the loop that makes it, Im not sure.